# Access ImageCollection of a UserControl in the Form Designer

Tags: c#, image, winforms, user-controls

I want to make a user control which acts like a `TabControl` but the tab page buttons should have big images. Therefore I want to have a property `Images` which adds images to the user control like an `ImageList`. For every image, the user control then generates a `PictureButton` and a corresponding panel. For that reason I added an `ImageList` to the user control and I've also tried to just add a collection of `Image`.

The problem is, that I cannot access this `ImageList` from the main form designer.
I've tried the following properties:

```
public Collection<Bitmap> Images { get; set; }

// ----

public ImageCollection Images { get; set; }

// ----

public List<Bitmap> Images { get; set; }

// ----

public ImageList Images { get; set; }
```

When I try to add an image to a `Collection<Bitmap>` or `List<Bitmap>` in the designer then Visual Studio crashes. I cannot use `Image` instead of `Bitmap`.

I know that I could use `TabControl` itself and give each `TabPage` an image, but I don't like the look of it.

So what's the best way to add a collection of images to a user control from the main form?

Comment: Do you instantiate new instances of these objects? I can't see that. i.e. `public List<Bitmap> Images { get; set; } = new List<Bitmap>();`.

Comment: @dr.null I've tried your suggestion with `List<Bitmap>` and `Collection<Bitmap>`. Sadly Visual Studio still crashes.

Comment: You need to do that for all. `ImageList`, `ImageCollection` ... etc. What is the last one? DevExpress stuff? Now, comment everything but the `ImageList` and try. Yes, VS sometimes doesn't complain and just crashes when you try to access `null` objects. So double check that.

Comment: Oh, I know that I'd need to do it for all of them. Maybe I wasn't clear enough with my description. I just need one of these properties at a time and these 4 properties where my attempts to get it to work. This is not DevExpress, it's pure WinForms ^^

Comment: I see. Then I think you have a `null` object that causes the crash. Btw: you can create a nice looking `TabControl` controls. Takeover the drawing and visualize it as you like. Do some researches on that. Maybe a screenshot for the desired output could help someone to assist you.

Comment: Yeah, drawing `TabControl` by my own seems to be the way then.